# JSON class definition for non-array parent property with unknown number of child fields

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

How to write a JSON class for the following when the number of fields in `"amounts"` is unknown.

```
{
    "amounts": {
        "a": 100,
        "b": 72
        ...
        ...
   }
}
```

- I do understand that `"amounts"` should have been an array, but I'm not
  at will to change this.
- All children of `"amounts"` are guaranteed to be simple key-value pairs with int values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> but I'm not at will to change this.

You can use `Dictionary<string, ...>` which is quite a common convention among JSON serializers in .NET (at least 2 of the most popular use it - Newtonsoft's Json.NET and System.Text.Json). For example:

```
public class MyWrapper
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> Amounts {get; set;}
}
```

P.S.

Depending on serializer/settings used you might need to annotate the property with attribute with property name matching the source json casing.

Answer (score 2):

As Guru Stron already mentioned - you can use `Dictionary<string, int>` for this. However, I believe a cleaner design will be like that:

```
{
    "amounts": [
        {
            "key": "a",
            "value": 100
        },
        {
            "key": "b",
            "value": 72
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

This will let you iterate over the `amounts` easily without being "surprised" by unexpected keys.
You can achieve this by creating an `Amount` object with 2 properties - `string key`, `int value`, and then `amounts` can be `List<Amount>`.

Besides clean code, this design will help you to add more properties to an "Amount" in future if needed, by simply adding another property to `Amount` class.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you can have duplicated keys, where the key "a" is set to different values. Dictionary implements 'IEnumerable', so you can still iterate with a 'foreach' or any other 'IEnumerable' extension.

Answer (score 0):

Since OP mentioned an array, just for a record, my 3 cents. In some cases using List (or custom class list) can be very usefull, since names of keys are unknown

```
    List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> amounts = 
          ((JObject)JObject.Parse(json)["amounts"])
         .Properties()
         .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(x.Name, (int)x.Value))
         .ToList();
```

Comment: Though it should be noted that according to the latest JSON RFC _"The names within an object SHOULD be unique"_ and Newtonsoft's Json.NET (at least in latest version) will have only the last of the duplicated keys (and actually handles deserializing to dictionary just fine, using only the latest of the duplicated keys).

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks for the comment, I am not talking about this case, It is just  for some special cases.

Comment: Which special cases? If you change OPs JSON to `{"amounts": {"a": 100, "a": 72}}` it will parse only the last one.

Comment: @GuruStron This json is not valid. Why are you trying to troll me? I told you that I really appreciated your comment

Comment: While it is not completely valid at least some online JSON validators produce only warnings and Newtonsoft's Json.NET handles it in the manner I have described - [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sNxl2A). I don't troll here, I use other places for such lowbrow fun.

Comment: _"I told you that I really appreciated your comment"_ -  the update appeared for me only after I've posted the comment with the JSON.